# access identifier of <input> in ng-disabled

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to disable input field until its dependent fields have valid value.
I want to have a generic function for this.
But for this, I need to know which input field's `ng-disabled` method is called.
I'll have a map, using which I will check if the modelValue of its dependent fields are defined and set `ng-disabled` based on this.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control"
ng-init="oeMinLength = '3'"
ng-model="vm.trade.BOAT_CUSTOMER_NAME"
ng-disabled="vm.dependencyValidation()"
id="fi-oe" name="oe">

<input type="text" class="form-control"
ng-model="vm.trade.BOAT_CONTACT"
ng-disabled="vm.dependencyValidation()"
id="fi-contact" name="contact">
```

Controller:

```
vm.dependencyValidation = function () {
    var identifier = 'contact';
    if (isEmpty(getDependent(identifier))) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        true;
    }
};
```

I do not want to pass the name/id as the parameter to `vm.dependencyValidation()`.

Comment: You do not `return true;`

Comment: you want to know in dependencyValidation() which input call the function ? why you do not want to pass the name/id as the parameter ?
in the dependencyValidation() function you cann access to the form with "this.form" ( the input should be in <form name="form"> )

Comment: I can access the form using scope as well. $scope.search where search is the name of my form. But how do I get to know what input has called this method?